# My Xbox 360 is displaying weirdly, what can I do?

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues

First off, it's WELL out of warranty.

Anyways the symptoms are thus: When I turn it on there is sometimes no picture, sometime there is picture but the resolution acts weird. Sometimes it plays fine.

I get sound regardless. I've tried swapping to other connectors and my other gaming consoles work fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well you've pretty much narrowed it down to your Xbox but just to be sure you could find a friend with one and have them try as well.

Comment: When there's no picture, does it display the text "E47" anywhere?

Comment: What do you mean the resolution acts weird? Are there green lines/bars going across the TV?

Comment: is your tv at least 60hz? if not, is your xbox set to 60hz? Otherwise, I would recommend trying out the hdmi cable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's dead, or dying. At least that is what turned out to be the case. I took it apart, cleaned off the CPU, re-applied thermal paste, and put it back together and got another 6 hours of operation before it died a final and definitive death.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the RROD warranty is for three years (from purchase, not since last replacement).  Just saying.  Otherwise I think you're looking for either a new console or a local repair shop.  Sorry I don't have any better news.

Comment: I'm not sure it would be a good idea to tell someone that should commit fraud. Probably a bad idea.

Comment: Edited due to my prior lack of good judgment.

Answer (score 1):

My xbox got a funny picture. Colors changed and it got quite fuzzy. Turned out that it was the component cable. So I got a hdmi adapter and used a hdmi cable instead. And that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation where one of the colors dropped out (blue I think), leaving me with a pink and green screen when playing games on my Xbox 360 (reminded me of my Apple II days). Anyways, after testing my TV with another HDMI device, other HDMI ports and a new HDMI cable I concluded that the video out system on my 360 was dying. $99 later I got a "new" refurbished Xbox 360 from Microsoft.

*As this isn't a Red Ring issue, you will likely have to pay $99 USD to fix your 360.*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your video cable is set to the correct setting (HDTV for Component, the other setting (I forget what it is called) for composite).  Also, make sure that your output in the settings is set to a resolution your TV can actually display properly - e.g. 720i, 1080i, 1080p, etc)